# How windows maps a file, which size is more 4gb?

Tags: windows, winapi

Memory mapped files mapped in address space. How windows map file, which size is more than 4 gb if address space is 4 gb?

Comment: You don't have to map the whole file at once, you use `MapViewOfFile` to map a section. If you try to map more than you have in your address space, it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the relevant API:

```
LPVOID WINAPI MapViewOfFile(
  _In_  HANDLE hFileMappingObject,
  _In_  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_  DWORD dwFileOffsetHigh,
  _In_  DWORD dwFileOffsetLow,
  _In_  SIZE_T dwNumberOfBytesToMap
);
```

This maps only part of the file, a view of the file. And the number of bytes that can be mapped at any one time is determined by the value of the `dwNumberOfBytesToMap`. Which has type `SIZE_T`, an integer that is pointer sized. In other words, in a 32 bit process, the upper limit of what can be mapped at any one time is 4GB.

If you are mapping a file that is larger than 4GB (indeed, you'll hit problems of contiguous address space long before you reach 4GB) then you'll need to map multiple views of the file in order to cover it in its entirety.